# USB Barcode Scanner and WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: c#, .net, usb, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to write a program that can will read a barcode scanner. In addition, I need it to read the input even when the application is not the window in focus (i.e., running in system tray, etc).

I found this article, titled [Distinguishing Barcode Scanners from the Keyboard in WinForms](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/), that seems to solve the exact problem. It is working pretty good, it detects my device and handles the WM_INPUT message.

However, it is checking to see if the RAWINPUT.keyboard.Message is WM_KEYDOWN (0x100). It never seems to receive this. The only line of code I've altered in the code provided in the [article](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/) is adding a Console.Out.WriteLine to output the actual values of that message:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("message: {0}", raw.keyboard.Message.ToString("X"));
if (raw.keyboard.Message == NativeMethods.WM_KEYDOWN)
{
    ....
```

Here is what it outputs:

```
message: B
message: 1000B
message: 3
message: 10003
message: 8
message: 10008
message: 3
message: 10003
message: 5
message: 10005
message: 3
message: 10003
message: 8
message: 10008
message: 8
message: 10008
message: 4
message: 10004
message: 9
message: 10009
message: 9
message: 10009
message: 3
message: 10003
```

The value I'm expecting to receive when this completes correctly is:

```
257232709
```

Which I verified by scanning to notepad.

I don't know if the Operation System is relevant here, but I figured I should mention that I'm running this in Windows 7 64 and Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 3.5. Scanner is a USB Barcode Scanner, Symbol LS2208, setup as "HID KEYBOARD EMULATION"

Answer (score 3):

just wanted to add, that microsoft POS.net, a free library from microsoft for building point of service systems, allows you to read most common barcode scanners, and gives you an event when a barcode is scanned. The library is free, and pretty well supported, and works with any barcode scanner that has an OPOS driver.

Comment: I googled and found this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/posScanner.aspx. Maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One non-software solution that could save you a lot of aggravation would be to get the RS-232 cable for this scanner and just read from the COM port.  Then you wouldn't need to care which window or control had focus.  That particular scanner has a COM port emulation driver, though it probably won't work under Windows 7.

Comment: I tried to add a link to the driver download page, but it didn't format correctly.  It's easy enough to Google, though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Tim. That was certainly an option, but I had to use a USB connection. Some coworkers had also suggested something similar, and writing a driver for it.. I wasn't ready to give up on the simpler solution and luckily didn't have.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that I don't really need the solution that the article in question solves. After reading over several times i realized that it was meant to handle the situation where you couldn't setup the scanner to use prefix and suffix data. Luckily for me, I can do this.

Otherwise, I chatted with the author of the article and we believe the issue was because I was running Windows 64. I think some of the code uses incorrect datatypes that may cause 64 bit to marshal the data incorrectly... I wasn't able to verify this though.

Was a great exercise in lower level windows programming though. Great resource at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) for using interops...